# I don't understand how Kirchhoff's Theorem can be true

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matrix-equations, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Kirchhoff's Matrix-Tree theorem states that the number of spanning trees of a graph G is equal to any cofactor of its Laplacian matrix.

Wouldn't this imply that all cofactors of a Laplacian matrix must be the same, as otherwise we could get a different number of spanning trees for the same graph depending on which cofactor we took?

But that's not necessarily the case. Example:

Consider the simple, undirected cycle graph on 4 nodes (1 is connected to 2 and 4, 2 is connected to 1 and 3, 3 is connected to 2 and 4, 4 is connected to 3 and 1).

When I find the cofactor along A11 I get 21, but when I find the cofactor along A12 I get 9. These are different! So this says that this graph has both 21 and 9 spanning trees?

Am I understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: You're right. The matrix-tree theorem does imply all the cofactors are equal. So now there are two possibilities. (1) The matrix-tree theorem is false. (2) You've made an arithmetic mistake in computations. Note also that the cycle on four vertices has exactly four spanning trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've made a mistake computing the Laplacian matrix.

I find \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 &0 &-1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}

You can check that any cofactor has determinant $4$, which you can check by inspection is the right number of trees.

Comment: Oh okay. What about with the wheel graph where there's a cycle of 4 like above but then also one vertex connected to all four of these vertices. The Laplacian would be: {{3,-1,0,-1,-1},{-1,3,-1,0,-1},{0,-1,3,-1,-1},{-1,0,-1,3,-1},{-1,-1,-1,-1,3}} correct? (Sorry, unsure about matrix formatting). I want to make sure I understand Laplacian. This one also gives me different cofactors @user4571

Comment: @User That can't be the right matrix, because the middle vertex has degree $4$.

Comment: Oh so it would be {{3,-1,0,-1,-1},{-1,3,-1,0,-1},{0,-1,3,-1,-1},{-1,0,-1,3,-1},{-1,-1,-1,-1,4}} ? @user4571

Comment: I see it now. They are all 45. I will keep playing around and practicing my Laplacians. Thank you!